# Secure Azure Functions App in another tenant

Tags: authentication, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C in Tenant A. A SPA web app (FE) and an API Functions App (Node.js) in Tenant B.

FE is using MSAL to require login with Azure AD B2C. I want the set up Authentication in the API to accept bearer access token from FE.

How can I configure Azure to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tenant that has your Azure Subscription which in turn has your resources doesn't really have to be the one used for App Level Authentication. It is just required RBAC.

The App Registrations for both could just be in the Azure AD B2C Tenant directly and you could provide the required details when setting it up like below

[image: add-an-identity-provider-azure-function]